# migrated db size is smaller than original

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I followed the heroku tutorial to upgrade my db from dev to basic, using the backups plugin.
everything seems to work just fine, but there is something that bothers me - the size of the new db is smaller than the size of the original db!

when I use pg info info, I get the following information

```
# New DB (10.7 MB)
Plan:        Basic
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-10-07 17:33 UTC
Data Size:   10.7 MB
Tables:      28
Fork/Follow: Unsupported

# Old DB (14.9 MB)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-04-25 13:46 UTC
Data Size:   14.9 MB
Tables:      28
Rows:        9717/10000 (In compliance, close to row limit)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

also, how can I get the rows count of the new db? (I want to validate it has the same number of rows)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue upon upgrading from Ronin to Standard Tengu (9.2 -> 9.3)

I believe the following answers it:

[PostgreSQL database size is less after backup/load on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505785/postgresql-database-size-is-less-after-backup-load-on-heroku)

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link**